# How to get a navbar behind a other screen

Tags: html, css, navbar

My question is how I can get the above display to dispear, after I click on the button in the top right corner.

[Where it should disapear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHAHE.png)

[The normal screen, where i click on the menubar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mT6Yk.png)

```
 <nav>
       <input type="checkbox" id="check">
       <label for="check" class="checkbtn">

        <img src="../Pictures/menu.png" onclick="changeinput()" style="margin-bottom:-8px;width: 40px;" alt="">
    </label>

        <label class="logo">VOCA.</label>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="./contact/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="./Aboutus/about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
        </ul>

    </nav>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can check if it is checked with css and then display your nav or don't display your nav.

```css
#check:checked ~ .nav-ul {
    display: none;
}

.nav-ul {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <input type="checkbox" id="check">
        <label for="check" class="checkbtn">

            <img src="../Pictures/menu.png" onclick="changeinput()" style="margin-bottom:-8px;width: 40px;" alt="">
        </label>

        <label class="logo">VOCA.</label>
        <ul class="nav-ul">
            <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="./contact/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="./Aboutus/about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
        </ul>

    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```